# Wordpress Custom Post Type rewrite page and category slug

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I have set up a custom post type

```
register_post_type( 'Communities',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Communities' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Community' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No Communities Found' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/%category%/communities', 'with_front' => false),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields' ),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-home'
    )
);
```

I have a pages setup with a city name that I need to remain as a page for different reasons, but I want communities in that city to be stored as a custom post type. I have setup categories for each city that I am adding communities to but I would like them to treat the cityname page as the parent.

like this

```
www.sitename.com/cityname/communities/communityname/
```

I would like cityname to be a page, communities to be an archive page and the communityname to be a single page.

Every solution I have found thus far generates 404 errors or conflicts with the parent page.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you, but first there are 2 things you should know.

1.) I wouldn't recommend this URL structure as it mandates that every entry have at least ONE category. It will always grab the first in the array. You'll need to write a small plugin to let your authors know. This may do the trick:

https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/require-post-category/

2.) Before you can view a post, you'll need to visit Settings > permalinks after you add the code so it will force a rewrite flush.

---

```
/**
 * Register Community Custom Post Type
 */
function community_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Communities',
        'singular_name'         => 'Community',
        'menu_name'             => 'Communities',
        'name_admin_bar'        => 'Communities',
        'archives'              => 'Community Archives',
        'attributes'            => 'Community Attributes',
        'parent_item_colon'     => 'Parent Community:',
        'all_items'             => 'All Communities',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Add New Community',
        'add_new'               => 'Add New',
        'new_item'              => 'New Community',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edit Community',
        'update_item'           => 'Update Community',
        'view_item'             => 'View Community',
        'view_items'            => 'View Communities',
        'search_items'          => 'Search Communities',
        'not_found'             => 'Community Not found',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'Not found in Trash',
        'featured_image'        => 'Featured Image',
        'set_featured_image'    => 'Set featured image',
        'remove_featured_image' => 'Remove featured image',
        'use_featured_image'    => 'Use as featured image',
        'insert_into_item'      => 'Insert into item',
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => 'Uploaded to this Community',
        'items_list'            => 'Communities list',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Communities list navigation',
        'filter_items_list'     => 'Filter Communities list',
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                  => '/%category%/communities',
        'with_front'            => true,
        'pages'                 => true,
        'feeds'                 => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => 'Community',
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category' ),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-universal-access',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'communities', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'community_post_type', 0 );

/**
 * Add category slug to community post links
 * @param  $post_link
 * @param  $id
 */

function my_commmunity_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'communities' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
        if( !empty($terms) ){
            return str_replace( '%category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_commmunity_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I used the code above and tested it in my custom theme as well as twentysixteen. It works great for the archive and single page, however the parent page is displaying as an archive. Also the other pages (ie. contact page etc) are generating 404 errors now.

Comment: It seems like its almost there... Do you have any suggestions I can try?

Comment: This fixes the 404 problem, but I still think the structure could be set up a little cleaner. Maybe a custom taxonomy instead of using the post's taxonomy. You could then use ACF to form a relationship. See the update below as it will show you how to rewrite your rules how you see fit.
https://gist.github.com/simplethemes/c9813cafef799000b04439ffae4a5c50

Comment: Thanks again. Yes I think you are right.. setting up a custom taxonomy we probably be the best bet.

Comment: I registered a custom taxonomy and the url structure seems to be good from the dashboard. However when you click the link to view the community it still generates a 404.

https://gist.github.com/pagetopixel/d103632eb7a0cbed3aaff0c5f30d0535

Comment: Have you visited the settings > permalinks to flush the rewrite cache?

Comment: change `$rules[ $term->slug .'/communities'. '/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type. 'communities_taxonomy=$matches[1]&name=$matches[1]';` to: `$rules[ $term->slug .'/communities'. '/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type. '&communities_taxonomy=$matches[1]&name=$matches[1]';`

Comment: ~I'm having the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209035/how-can-i-add-a-custom-meta-value-to-the-slug-for-custom-post-type?noredirect=1#comment83515519_48209035 where `post_type_link` updates the permalinks in WP Admin, but the URL rewriting doesn't get affected, and I can't add the custom meta value to the rewrite rule.